# How to execute sql scripts other than OSQL command?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my product we are using OSQL to execute the sql script files. Unfortunatly some clients don't have OSQL installed in their machine. They don't agree to install sql management studio for license issues.

Is there any alternative to execute the sql scripts rather than OSQL through c# ?

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, you should be using `SQLCMD` .... that should be installed by a standard SQL Server installation I believe

Comment: Thank you. Can i use sqlcmd utility in my project? because sql server installed in the server. The client doesn't have sql server and sqlcmd ?

Comment: If your client uses a SQL Server based solution, then there **must be** SQL Server somewhere - and that SQL Server somewhere has `SQLCMD` included. Your clients must have `SQLCMD` somewhere. I don't think you can just distribute `SQLCMD` with your own applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLCMD.EXE` will be installed in the SQL Server `binn` directory on the server. You will need SQLCMD.EXE on the client, where your application runs. You can install the SQLCMD.EXE and other command line utilities separately, see [Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server®](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=36433).

But is not necessary to install SQLCMD, writing a C# script executor is fairly trivial. In fact I wrote one myself, see https://github.com/rusanu/DbUtilSqlCmd and is also [available as a NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/com.rusanu.DbUtilSqlCmd/).

Answer (score 2):

I think SSMS is free for download from microsoft portal and there are no licence issues with it. Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593)